# systemd disable pulseaudio system mode

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, systemd

While troubleshooting a problem with VMWare disconnecting audio device during Ubuntu boot (18.04.1 LTS Ubuntu Desktop), I have isolated the problem to be **systemd** running **pulseaudio** in system mode before the login screen show up. **pulseaudio** runs in user mode just fine after logging in, and that is what I need.

My question is how to disable **pulseaudio** (which is part of sound.target) in **systemd**, before the user login screen.

Answer (score 4):

Try first to stop and disable pulseaudio

```
systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.socket
systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.service
```

or

```
sudo systemctl stop pulseaudio
sudo systemctl disable  pulseaudio
```

and eventually

```
sudo systemctl mask pulseaudio
```

to prevent that other services  start pulseaudio again.

Take a look at

```
man pulse-daemon.conf
```

This man describes the PulseAudio daemon configuration file.

```
   The  PulseAudio sound server reads configuration directives from a con‐
   figuration file on startup. If the per-user  file  ~/.config/pulse/dae‐
   mon.conf  exists,  it  is used, otherwise the system configuration file
   /etc/pulse/daemon.conf is used. In addition to those main  files,  con‐
   figuration  directives  can  also  be  put  in  files under directories
   ~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf.d/  and  /etc/pulse/daemon.conf.d/.   Those
   files  have  to  have  the .conf file name extension, but otherwise the
   file names can be chosen freely. The files under daemon.conf.d are pro‐
   cessed  in alphabetical order. In case the same option is set in multi‐
   ple files, the last file to set an option overrides earlier files.  The
   main daemon.conf file is processed first, so options set in files under
   daemon.conf.d override the main file.
```

One of these settings is

```
   daemonize=  Daemonize after startup. Takes a boolean value, defaults to
               no. The --daemonize command line option takes precedence.
```

Open the `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf` and set

```
daemonize = no
```

Open the local configuration file  `~/.config/pulse/client.conf`

Uncomment the following line

```
autospawn = no
```